# Design Database for Hosting Billing/Subscription System

Tags: database-design

I'm creating a billing system for hosting application..

So, basically,

users can buy hosting and domains, or can buy clouds and create there their own servers.

There also should be addons.

Addon can be applied to any type of package. So, user can add "server management" to a server from cloud. Or add "cloud management" for a whole cloud..

Hosting and domains are prepaid things.. so user pays in advance.. but clouds - users register in a cloud and then can create servers - and we then invoice them once a month for cloud usage (not for each server).

This is my db design: http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/app#agdkYmRzZ25ycg8LEgZTY2hlbWEY-pK0BAw

Could you comment on here what is bad with it and how to improve it?

Thing to mention: clouds and addons are paid for a usage time, so if addon was active 2 days and user then removed it - then we should invoice user for 2 days only..

Comment: Please can you explain why you think the design is bad first?

Comment: cloud is the issue.. price is not known. It's a dynamic value which changes every second. So I either have to grab statistics every hour/day to have a price, or to grab needed price at time of making invoice.. It means that in `orders` price for clouds/servers will be always 0 (because im generating recurring prices in advance). Have no idea how to improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I can see immediately is with the addons. There is no link between a user and what addons he/she has chosen. If you wanted to know which addons a user has chosen it looks like you cannot satisfy that query.

Also I can't see in your design the concept of one-to-many relationship between a package and the addons. A package could have more than one addons and you need to model that.

This brings me to my next point, the orders table. There you just have the packageId. But you don't capture the addons bolted to that package. That is a flaw as you will not be able to tell which customer has order a particular addon to a package or the reverse query. So you need to re-model that part of your design.

Another issue: an invoice typically has an orderId associated to it. An orderId does not exist on your invoice table.

If you update your model, I will review it again later. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Addons - when user chooses and addon I want it to be added to the packages table as a subpackage for the choosen package. That's why there is no link, it will be just subpackage with `parent_id` set to parent package. Then with orders - as addon will be a regular package - I can add it as a separate order row. It's bad?

Comment: "If you wanted to know which addons a user has chosen it looks like you cannot satisfy that query." - i can query `packages` table: select  from packages where type='addon' and user_id=123/* and parent_id=456*/

Comment: Yes but that won't tell you which type of addon the customer has chosen. There is no addon id association.

Comment: typically, that's not good database design. when representing one-to-many relationships like this, we reference the foreign keys of the other tables.

Comment: And for cloud - I want to save cloud credentials in `data` column too. Is there a better idea? I know I can add a separate column for addon id but then it is losing of packages generalization.. so.. addon_id for addons and then user/password for clouds.. and then who know what for other packages..

Comment: yes, i know, thats denormalization - but there is very different data for different packages..

Comment: and then as I want cloud servers to be different packages - I will save for tham their identifiers in data too.. thats going to be a db nightmare.. so.. looking for something more reliable

Comment: a solution can be to have, say, 12 columns named extra_value1.. extra_value12 and save additional data there.. but its again.. identifiers will be represented as strings.. Or to have special table for each type of package with its data, thats a more reliable solution, how you think?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I was about to say. Make separate tables for each package. Separate table for your addons. Then you need a table, let's call it User_Choice. That will contain the userid, packageid, addonId. In your order table, you will reference just the userChoiceId only.

Comment: Or clean up your existing Package table. Take out the user id column Have only your package details (no addon info), just package attributes and type. List all your products here. And have the User_Choice table as above.

Comment: This will allow you to query anything about a user's order. Currently that's hard to do with your design IMO. You will also have a more normalised/cleaner structure

Comment: nvm, gotcha. put there only general info

Comment: The User_Choice table will serve that purpose. It will tell you what each user has chosen. Therefore you don't need it in the Packages table. That table will just contain what you have to offer the customers.

Comment: ok.. so then prices and periods should probably go to user_choice too.. and then more specific info like passwords and server ids should go to specific tables like cloud_package, server_package, domain_package

Comment: No. Normalise this part of your design as well. Basically what you want it to separate out/normalise every concept in your system, from price schedule, to periods etc. What you end up with is identifiers which you can then play with. Say I have a PriceSchedule Table and a Period Table, each with identifiers. I can then associate any PriceScheule and Period to any package I want in the Package table. The passwords and server ids, are they for the user?

Comment: yes, user can register their account in a cloud (it's a  different service to where we have API) and then create as many servers as they want there, and each server we have to assign to user in billing system and then can apply addons to any server.

Comment: by PriceShedule you mean generate dates for next billing calculation?

Comment: So again, for a user you will have a one-to-many relationship with a table that holds your cloud server information. YOu will then have a table called UserCloudChoice for example that will link a user id to a cloud server id(s) and a packageId.

Comment: Yes you could model the price schedule like that. It's more flexible. In different periods you could set the price to be different. All you need to say then is that I am going to assign priceSchedule X to customer Y for period Z.

Comment: how to deal with recurring periods?

Comment: so, say, im going to bill user at 1st day of every month, but user has subscribed to package at middle of month..

Comment: i then should bill them in current month only a half of price

Comment: that's fine and has nothing to do with the design. that's more on the business logic, you could write a SP to work the pro-rated amount when a new user signs up and insert the adjusted price for that period.